# Cannot convert alpha-numeric values in a dataset to just numeric

Tags: r

I'm trying to get the m/z values and intensities of an experiment plotted as the x and y coordinates. I use the Cardinal MSI package to load in my data as nothing else can read my data files and average all intensities across a dataset for each m/z value. This works fine, but I then am left with a value that includes the format "m/z = 900.01" for the m/z value and just a number for the intensity.

So far, I've tried just using

```
data <- gsub("m/z = ", "", data)
```

which just eliminates the m/z value altogether.
I've also tried converting to a dataframe instead of a value, this works fine but the m/z value is then a set of titles for the intensity. Again, trying the gsub removes the m/z value completely. Is there another way to remove the "m/z = " and get just the number that follows it, with that still connected to the intensity value? Thanks!

Comment: `as.numeric(sub("m/z = ", "", data))` should work if the data is as you describe. If it doesn't work, please share some sample data with `dput`. Just a few values would be fine, e.g., `dput(head(data))`. This will give us a copy/pasteable version of your data with all the class information.

Comment: Please put the `dput` into your question in a code block. The comment formatting is mangling it.

Comment: Here is the dput output: ```c(m/z = 899.91 = 0.618620349367962, m/z = 900.36 = 1.35811776221143, m/z = 900.88 = 0.914331078627176, m/z = 901.33 = 0.70771055200515``` I'm beginning to see the problem - it wasn't showing the m/z = 900.36 = 1.35 portion before. Still, I'm not sure what to do; the as.numeric removes all m/z values.

Comment: Don't delete any backticks, they're important! R uses backticks for non-standard names (your names have `/` and spaces which make them non-standard). Instead, click the "edit" button (above the comments, below the question) and put the `dput()` result in a proper codeblock in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a *named vector*, where, e.g., the name `"m/z = 899.91"` has the value `0.6186...`, the name `"m/z = 900.36"` has the value `1.35811...`, etc. Your vector is numeric, and the values are all those less-than-one parts.

The 899.91, 900.36, etc. are part of the *names*. So `as.numeric(gsub("m/z = ", "", names(data)))` should get you the numeric part of the names.

You might want to create a data frame with one column for m/z, and one column for intensity:

```
my_data = data.frame(
  mz = as.numeric(gsub("m/z = ", "", names(data))),
  intensity = data
)
```

You can then `plot(my_data)`, or make other, fancier plots.